# Invertibility of a matrix whose entries are certain binomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $l$ be a positive integer. Does the matrix
$$
  M_l \ := \ \left( \binom{l-(2p+1)}{j} \right)_{0\leq p,j \leq[(l-1)/2]}
$$
have nonzero determinant?

Comment: Have you searched for "Vandermonde determinant"?

Comment: Yes, but Vandermonde determinant didn't solve the problem.
I found a paper that solves the problem but to a much more general case. I would like a more simpler solution, I believe  it exists.

Comment: @JasonStarr How do you reduce this to Vandermonde? Just curious :)

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev.  For elements $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}$ in a commutative ring $R$, the Vandermonde determinant $\text{det}(a_i^j)_{0\leq i,j\leq n-1}$ equals $0!\cdot 1!\cdots (n-1)!$ times the determinant $\text{det}(\binom{a_i}{j})_{0\leq i,j\leq n-1}$.  Thus, the determinant above is, up to a product of factorials, a Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: @JasonStarr: thanks, this is nice. For proof, I guess, this is the interpolation by Newton "monomials" rather than conventional ones, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a nice result of Gessel and Viennot that computes your determinant in terms of NE lattice paths.  The original paper is available [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870885901215).  Aigner and Ziegler also give a nice exposition of this result in their [Proofs From the Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642008550).

Comment: Thank you Chris. The paper has a very general result, I wanted some more direct thing. I'll look in the book.

Comment: @Liliam, I think if you take $k=\left\lfloor\frac{\ell-1}{2}\right\rfloor$, $a_i=2i$ and $b_j=j$ in their Theorem 1, then you get something pretty close to your determinant.

Comment: Chris, the book solved my problem, thank you so much.